# Splitting a string and assigning them to a variable

Tags: python

```
class Candidates:

    def __init__(self):
        with open("GSUCandidates.txt", 'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
        GSUCandidates = set ([s.strip() for s in lines])
        print(GSUCandidates)
        Candidate1, Candidate2, Candidate3, Candidate4 = GSUCandidates.myString.split(' ', 1)
        print(Candidate1)
        print(Candidate2)
        print(Candidate3)
        print(Candidate4)

candidates = Candidates()
```

I'm trying to assign 4 full names that I've read from my text file and assign each full name to a variable?
https://gyazo.com/08ce5f9fd996a8975d9474b5408aebc1

Comment: What is `GSUCandidates.myString` supposed to be? `GSUCandidates` is a set of strings.

Comment: You have already stored all the names in  `set` which you can iterate over. Why do you need to set each individual candidate to a separate variable?

Comment: What problem are you having? Can you please show the error you are getting, or the wrong output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to call `split()`. `readlines()` already split the file into a string for each line. Just assign them to the variables.

```
Candidate1, Candidate2, Candidate3, Candidate4 = GSUCandidates
```

Although any time you find yourself naming variables like this, you probably shouldn't be using separate variables at all. Just put them in a list, and index it when you want specific elements.